# ¿Cómo hacer una copia de seguridad de usuarios y privilegios en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo MySQL Community V.8.0.19 y Workbench sobre Windows y mi duda surge con las copias de seguridad.

He encontrado información y he sabido realizar "copia de seguridad" de todas las bases de datos instaladas, pero no encuentro cómo hacer copia y migración de los usuarios y sus privilegios.

**AMPLIO** captura parcial de pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La base de datos [`mysql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant-tables.html) contiene toda esa información.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda la información relacionada con roles y privilegios está almacenada en la base de datos [`mysql` (ver documentación)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant-tables.html).

Aquí te dejo un extracto de la documentación que enlazo:

> La base de datos `mysql` contiene estas tablas con la información de acceso:
>
> - `user`: Cuentas de usuario, privilegios globales estáticos y otras columnas no relacionadas con privilegios.
> - `global_grants`: Privilegios globales dinámicos.
> - `db`: Privilegios a nivel de base de datos.
> - `tables_priv`: Privilegios a nivel de tabla.
> - `columns_priv`: Privilegios a nivel de campo.
> - `procs_priv`: Privilegios de procedimientos almacenados y funciones.
> - `proxies_priv`: Privilegios de usuarios de proxy.
> - `default_roles`: Roles de usuario por defecto.
> - `role_edges`: Edges for role subgraphs.
> - `password_history`: Histórico de cambios de contraseña.

Por lo pronto, si has realizado una copia de seguridad de todas las bases de datos, has realizado una copia de seguridad de los permisos, roles, etc que se almacenan en la base de datos `mysql`.

Si quieres migrar de un servidor de bases de datos MySQL a otro diferente debes tener en cuenta datos adicionales como diferencias de versión entre uno y otro. En ese caso es probable que esta base de datos tenga tablas de más o de menos o en ellas campos de más o de menos, necesitando unas acciones previas o posteriores para corregir estas diferencias entre versiones.

Edito: Tras compartir la captura de pantalla de tu cliente y confirmar que estás con un usuario privilegiado, he encontrado este enlace con información acerca de [cómo mostrar las tablas del sistema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-navigator.html):

> *Internal schemas, such as `performance_schema`, `information_schema`, and `mysql`, are hidden by default. Select the **Show Metadata and Internal Schemas** preference (see **Preferences: SQL Editor: Main**) to list them in the object browser.*

En castellano:

> *Esquemas internos, como `performance_schema`, `information_schema` y `mysql`, están ocultos por defecto. Seleccione en las preferencias **Show Metadata and Internal Schemas** (ver **Preferences: SQL Editor: Main**) para mostrarlos en el navegador de objetos.*

Comment: El tema es que la BBDD:mysql no la veo por ninguna parte.
Amplio con una imagen en la pregunta inicial.

Comment: Eso es porque no estás iniciando sesión con un usuario privilegiado. ¿Qué usuario usas para iniciar sesión? ¿Has probado con `root`? Sin los privilegios adecuados no podrás obtener la información del servidor de origen ni tampoco aplicarlos al de destino.

Comment: Estoy como root

Comment: Entonces tu cliente te está ocultando esa base de datos (probablemente en un intento de evitar que se modifique por error). ¿Qué herramienta usas para copia de seguridad y restauración de los datos? Te puedo proporcionar parámetros para que incluyan esa base de datos.

Comment: He encontrado este enlace con información sobre tu problema con ese cliente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-navigator.html *Internal schemas, such as `performance_schema`, `information_schema`, and `mysql`, are hidden by default. Select the **Show Metadata and Internal Schemas** preference (see **Preferences: SQL Editor: Main**) to list them in the object browser.*

Comment: Estoy en ello, pero me fuiste de gran ayuda.
Gracias.